# fbDidExtendAccessToken:expiresAt: not returning 60-day token

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook

Before I start, I'd like to state that I am using the new Facebook iOS-SDK (January 18, 2012 release), and setting 'deprecate offline_access' to enabled in my app's Facebook setting page.

When the `fbDidExtendAccessToken:expiresAt` method is called/reached via the `extendAccessTokenIfNeeded` (or `extendAccessToken`) methods, it returns the same token (e.g., the one expiring within a few hours). Also, the token is de-authenticated when restarting app, requiring the user to re-authenticate upon each fresh-launch (this may be a separate issue, or a bug on my end).

The expected results should be the following: Token should expire in 60 days, and token should exist in NSUserDefaults when restarting app.

I do not observe this happening.

Is anyone else having this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left a post on Facebook's Support forums. Facebook shot me an email saying that they have escalated this bug to 'Medium' priority as of today.

Here's the post: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/319523108090699